# Is there any possibility of obtaining an asymptotic approximation (instead of numerical solutions) of such a 2nd-order homogeneous ODE in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, asymptotics

Here is a typical linear ordinary differential equation with variable coefficients: $$\ddot{x\hspace{0pt}}(t)+\left(\frac{\ln t}t\right)^{\!2}x(t)=0\text.$$ Now I intend to investigate the (leading) asymptotic behavior of solutions for $x$ as $t\to+\infty$, but regrettably,

```
(*System`AsymptoticDSolveValue[Derivative[2][x][t]+(Log[E,t]/t)^2*x[t]==0,x[t],t->DirectedInfinity[1]]
```

just returns an unevaluated function call (without any messages). Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a symbolic solution, whose asymptotic expansion may be obtained:

```
ode = (Log[t]^2 x[t])/t^2 + x''[t] == 0;
ode /. x -> Function[t, y[Log[t]]] /. t -> Exp[u] // 
 Simplify[#, u \[Element] Reals] &
(*  u^2 y[u] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[u] == Derivative[1][y][u]  *)

ysol = DSolve[
  u^2 y[u] + y''[u] == Derivative[1][y][u], y, u]
(*
{{y -> Function[{u}, 
    E^(u/2 - (I u^2)/2) C[1] HermiteH[-(1/2) + I/8, (-1)^(1/4) u] + 
     E^(u/2 - (I u^2)/2) C[
      2] Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 - I/16, 1/2, I u^2]]}}
*)

xOfU = x[t] /. x -> Function[t, y[Log[t]]] /. t -> Exp[u] /. 
    First@ysol // Simplify[#, u \[Element] Reals] &;
xOfT = xOfU /. y -> Function[u, x[Exp[u]]] /. u -> Log[t] // 
   Simplify[#, t > 0] &;
xsol = x -> Function @@ {t, xOfT}
(*
x -> Function[t, t^(-(1/2) I (I + Log[t])) *
   (C[1] HermiteH[-(1/2) + I/8, (-1)^(1/4) Log[t]] +
     C[2] Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 - I/16, 1/2, I Log[t]^2])]
*)

ode /. xsol // FullSimplify
(*  True  *)

Series[x[t] /. xsol, {t, Infinity, 1}, Assumptions -> t > 0]
(* Long output *)
```

Answer (score 3):

It can't do it. Most likely due to this

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[x''[t] + (Log[t]/t)^2*x[t] == 0, x[t], {t, m, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Limit[sol, m -> Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One possibility is obtain the expansion about `m`, and keep increasing `m` to see how the leading terms in the series change?

```
 Limit[sol, m -> 10000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

btw, doing change of variables on the ode `t->1/z` and looking at asymptotic expansion around `z=0` will have problem of course. It can not do it.